# Calling an activity from a custom dialog

Tags: android, android-activity, customdialog

I guess this is just a simple question (I’m such a noob…)
I have this custom dialog box that has 3 buttons in it.

Now I want to call an activity from one of the buttons so
I tried this:

```
public class picturedialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {
    Button Camera;

    public picturedialog (Context context){
        super (context);
        setContentView(R.layout.picturedialog);

        Camera = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.pdButton1);

        Camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                dismiss();

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), CameraActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);

            }
        });
...
}
```

Then the red squiggly line appears on startActivity(myIntent).
Upon hovering on it, eclipse tells me this: “The method startActivity(Intent) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){}”
Ehhh? Please orient me on how to do this properly.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure you are overcomplicating with subclassing from `Dialog`. Try to follow to the dialog tutorial - https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#ShowingADialog

Note that dialogs are created on the fly (in `Activity.onCreateDialog()`) without the need to have your own custom dialog classes. Since you set a listener being inside of the wrapping activity (if you follow the tutorial), then you are able to call `startActivity(myIntent)`, because all the fields/methods of a wrapping class instance are available for an instance of an inner class.

Comment: Thanks. I shall try this. :D The tutorial I followed was a pretty basic one and it involved creating a separate class from my main class. :( I thought at first that the reason why my code didn't work was because I was calling an activity from a non-activity class. PS: I seldom read the android documentation because it's not that friendly to new programmers. But I shall try this time, I have to make things work!!! Neh neh! neh!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the name of your Activity is A, then you just do:

```
   A.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

The problem arises because "this" inside your inner class refers to the object of that inner class, when what you want is the object of the enclosing Activity. A.this will refer to that.

If you aren't enclosing this class in an Activity, then try calling the startActivity from method using the context that you passed into the method, e.g. context.startActivty(myIntent).
The startActivity method belongs to the Context class.